# How can I disable Chrome/ium's Wrench menu?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, appmenu

Chromium now supports Unity menu bar integration. Because I can use the menu by moving my mouse to the panel, I have no need for the wrench menu. Is there a way to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a while and couldn't find any extension or option to do what you asked. The Google wrench is the only way to get to the settings for most operating systems, so my guess is Google has locked down options, such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

In settings from Chomium you can choose in the "private" options menu beetween system menu theme and chromium classic. Chrome classic disables menu bar integration and the other enables that and disables the chromiums own menu bar.

Comment: I am wanting to disable the Wrench menu/button: http://i.imgur.com/OPLe3.png